# Filtering Groups by createdDateTime

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I`m trying to filter Office 365 Groups based on their creation time using Microsoft Graph.

Unfortunately, all `DateTime` formats produce a `400 - BadRequest - Invalid filter` clause response.
I tried below filter clauses:

- `/v1.0/groups?$filter=createdDateTime/DateTime gt 2016-10-24T14:21:03.000Z`
- `/v1.0/groups?$filter=createdDateTime gt '2016-10-24T14:21:03.000Z'`

Could you please help me out on what I`m missing?

Comment: HI, Did you resolve it? I have the same problem  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid Groups do not support filtering by `createdDateTime` or `gt` today.

If you would like to see this added to Microsoft Graph, you can submit this idea to [Microsoft Graph's UserVocie](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).